# Debug a single python file in Visual Studios with F5

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging

I am using Visual Studios 2015 for creating python programs. Each file is a separate program and hence I wish to debug each one of them separately.

I know you can do this by going to : 
`Project Properties -> General -> Start Up File` and type in my file name each time.

I want to know if there is a simpler way, that just runs the current `.py` file  everytime I hit **F5** Just like how it is in IDLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this isnt possible. Right clicking on the file seems to be the only way to run a python file in visual studios.

Answer (score 1):

Key thing is to deprive VS of a startup file and then it's going to run whatever file is in the active tab, wherever it came from.

1. Open project properties and delete the name of the startup file

   - so that the project has none
2. Open any .py file in VS (or drag&drop)
3. Make sure it's active tab (cursor is in it)
4. Right-Click, Start with Debugging

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well using PTVS with VS2013 update 4 inside a Django project.

So far the only way I have been able to get this to work is to right click on the project name in solution explorer, select properties and change the debug Launch mode to "Standard Python Launcher" and then right-clicking on the python script in solution explorer and choosing "Start with Debugging".  Otherwise I get an interpreter not found error even though it is specified in my debug options in the project properties.

I will update post if I find a better solution.